# React: How to call a function that has a hook (the calling function has hooks as well)

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, components

I have several components which make http calls to backend. Each call has to have a valid token. We had a duplicated code that I managed to outsource to a single component using createContext hook. However, it was rather a lucky punch that it works and I'd like to solve it differently.

So I'd like to have a reusable component

```
import {
InteractionRequiredAuthError,
InteractionStatus,
} from "@azure/msal-browser";
import { useMsal } from "@azure/msal-react";



export function TokenSupplier() {

    const { instance, accounts } = useMsal();

    console.log("in supplier");
    const accessTokenRequest = {
        scopes: [myScope],
        account: accounts[0],
    };

    instance
        .acquireTokenSilent(accessTokenRequest)
        .then((accessTokenResponse) => {
            // Acquire token silent success
            return accessTokenResponse.accessToken;
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            if (error instanceof InteractionRequiredAuthError) {
                instance
                    .acquireTokenPopup(accessTokenRequest)
                    .then(function (accessTokenResponse) {
                        // Acquire token interactive success
                        return accessTokenResponse.accessToken;
                    })
                    .catch(function (error) {
                        // Acquire token interactive failure
                        console.log(error);
                    });
            }
            console.log(error);
        });
    return null;

}
```

Yes, I want this function be stateless and just return the generated token.

My problem is that when I call this function from some component I get the error

***Warning: Cannot update a component (`MsalProvider`) while rendering a different component (`TriggerDocumentCreationPage`).***

```
import { useState } from 'react';
import { TokenSupplier } from '../store/token-provider';

function TriggerDocumentCreationPage() {
    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);

    const token = TokenSupplier();
```

Except for using useContext hook (which somehow works), how would you solve this? Any feedback is highly appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Could you provide sandbox with minimum reproducible example? We can't see the implementation of `MsalProvider` and how it is connected to rest of components.

Comment: the MsalProvider comes from the Microsoft Authentication Library (MSAL), which is imported using "@azure/msal-react". Unfortunately, I can't provide more info due to security reasons..

Comment: Your `TriggerDocumentCreationPage` component fetches token on every rerender, which is not the desired behavior. You can make it return callback which is then executed in controlled conditions (for example, inside useEffect).

Comment: the problem is that I'd like to call the function **TokenSupplier** and have it return a valid current token without the warning.. **Warning: Cannot update a component (MsalProvider) while rendering a different component (XY)**